# Database schema library

Tags: .net, database-schema

Is there any library for .NET that allows user to manipulate database schema from code using the same code for different DB providers?

I built my own utility library that allows me to create or alter tables or columns but I wonder if there is already such a library. One that also includes constraints and indexes.

I use something like this:

```
DBManager db = new DBManager(connString);
DBTable persons = new DBTable("Persons");
orders.Columns.Add(new DBColumn("Name", DBType.Varchar, 100);
orders.Columns.Add(new DBColumn("Birthday", DBType.Date);
db.CreateTable(persons);
db.AddColumn("Persons", new DBColumn("CityID",DBType.Int);
db.DropColumn("Persons", "Birthday");
```

Of course, this isn't hardcoded. I want to add a feature to my application to allow users to specify they own entities that can be stored in database and then my app will use the library to create the underlying database table.

Comment: if you have your own utility why are you looking for one that exists elsewhere? Which database are you using (mysql, mssql, pgsql?)

Comment: As I asked, I want support for multiple providers and management for constraints and indexes. Also, such library requires diverse skills, more than one person can handle.

Answer (score 1):

I only know **how to query database schema** from code using the same code for different DB providers.

Since dotnet 2.0 most dotnet-providers implement **System.Data.Common.DbConnection** .

With the `System.Data.Common.DbConnection.GetSchema()` function (without parameter) you can ask the provider 
which collectionNames it supports (tables, views, stored procedures, .....)
These can be used with `GetSchema(collectionName)` to get more details. Among the details are even supported datatypes and regular expressions to validate fieldnames.

You can also look at the **[MyGeneration project source](http://mygeneration.sourceforge.net/)** . Its [mymeta](https://mygeneration.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mygeneration/trunk/mymeta/) engine builds a common api around different databaseproviders.

NHibernate must have something like a common database-provider as well. But i havent looked at its sourcecode yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Server Management Objects
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx

If it is SQL Server you are working with of course...